# How do I safely cast between any numeric types with clipping if required?

Tags: c++

I'd like a function of the following form

```
template <typename T, typename U>
U clipAndCast(T x)
{
  ... 
  return y;  
 },
```

where y is x cast to type U, but with x clipped if required so that this cast is well-defined.

Is there a library or boost function do to this? I can't find one, so if not what's the best way to write such a function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about clipped? Can you give an example of what you'd be passing in? Also not sure why you'd be using T and U in this case.

Comment: For example, if casting a float to an unsigned char, all values < 0 would produce an output of 0, and all values > 255 would produce values of 255.

Comment: This is about **converting**, not **casting**.

Comment: @KyleC - no, that won't limit the values when converting to a smaller type.

Comment: What's the use cases for this? You can potentially run into problems with this.

Comment: @KyleC - this is a saturating conversion. As an example, if you're controlling the volume of a stereo system and the calculated value is lower then the minimum setting, you probably don't want it to wrap around to a large value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is to test whether the value coming in is greater than or equal to the minimum value of the type going out and less than or equal to the maximum value of the type going out. You can use `std::numeric_limits<U>::min()` and `std::numeric_limits<U>::max()` to get the minimum and maximum values.

Comment: To test whether x > std::numeric_limits<U>::max(), wouldn't I need to first convert x to a value of type U?

Comment: No, comparisons do the usual arithmetic promotions, so the smaller type gets promoted to the larger type for the comparison (but be careful of mixing unsigned and signed types).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Boost's Numerical Conversions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/index.html) library.